# Sql error in my php source

Tags: php, sql

i have php sql problem . this is my source

```
$idtoshowvalue = $_GET['value'];
$dbcheck = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aria_prodces WHERE produce_id='$idtoshowvalue'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($dbcheck);
if ((isset($_COOKIE['ariaclientusername'])) && isset($_COOKIE['ariaclientpassword']) && isset($_COOKIE['ariaclientid'])) { 

$ariaclientid = $_COOKIE['ariaclientid'];

$dbcheck2 = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aria_clients WHERE cli_id='$ariaclientid'") or die(mysql_error());
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($dbcheck2);
```

this source get value from url kile this :
`index.php?value=12`
but when i put (`'`) to this url (`index.php?value=12'`) i see this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''12''' at line 1
```

what is the problem? how can i fix this bug?

Comment: I'd be more worried about the [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities...

Comment: [`index.php?value=12';%20DROP%20TABLE%20users;%20--%20`](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution..

```
     $idtoshowvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);
     $dbcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aria_prodces WHERE produce_id='".$idtoshowvalue."'") or die(mysql_error());
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($dbcheck);
     if ((isset($_COOKIE['ariaclientusername'])) && isset($_COOKIE['ariaclientpassword']) && isset($_COOKIE['ariaclientid'])) { 

      $ariaclientid = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['ariaclientid']);

      $dbcheck2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aria_clients WHERE cli_id='".$ariaclientid."'") or die(mysql_error());
      $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($dbcheck2);
```

Comment: And what about `$ariaclientid = $_COOKIE['ariaclientid'];` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dbcheck = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aria_prodces WHERE produce_id='%s'") or die(mysql_error());
$dbcheck = sprintf($dbcheck, mysql_real_escape_string($idtoshowvalue));
$row = mysql_fetch_array($dbcheck);
```

The apostrophe is causing the error.  It needs to be escaped.
[mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

This function is deprecated.  You should switch over to using [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)